# Unable to create file - Resnet50 model api for classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, resnet

I have built a classification model in keras and I'm now learning how to deploy the model at the production level using Flask.

While loading and saving the Resnet50 model for this from Keras I am getting below error.

> Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\models', errno = 13, error message = 'Permission denied', flags = 13, o_flags = 302)

**Code:**

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
model.save(r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\models')
print('Model loaded. Check http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
```

Comment: I am no expert but it says Permission denied in the error. Maybe try to run the program with different location, for example,  C:\some_folder\models

Comment: Hi, tried this too but it did not work